# How do I combine multiple curves and plot with R and ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to simulate a chromatogram by plotting multiple `dnorm` curves in `ggplot` similar to this:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x = x)) +
  mapply(function(mean, sd, col) {
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean, sd = sd), col = col)
  },
  mean = c(0, 1, .5), 
  sd = c(1, .5, 2), 
  col = c('red', 'blue', 'green')) +
  xlim(-5, 5) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: Plotted separately]

However, instead of plotting separately I would like to combined them by summing the curves at each point on the x-axis (i.e. `dnorm(x, 0, 1) + dnorm(x, 1, 0.5) + dnorm(x, 0.5, 2)` where -5 < x < 5):

[image: Combined]

I could do this numerically, but would prefer to use `stat_function()` (or similar) if possible. Please advise.

Comment: I would like to point out that summing density values like this doesn't make sense to me. The result is not a density curve.

Comment: Thanks Roland. Normal distributions represent peaks in chromatographic separations. When they overlap, such as in these simulations, they need to be deconvoluted to get any real meaning from them. You are correct that it makes no sense, however, simulating this behaviour can be used to test peak detection algorithms for HPLC and GC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
ggplot(data.frame(x = 0), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) rowSums(mapply(dnorm, mean = c(0, 1, .5), 
                                                 sd = c(1, .5, 2), MoreArgs = list(x = x)))) + 
  xlim(-5, 5) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: resulting plot]