# How can I increase the axis resolution with `ggplot` and `xlim()`

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to simulate a profile from a scientific experiment separating 3 compounds with HPLC.

I am plotting peaks with `ggplot()`, but get really poor resolution on the x-axis. How can I increase the number of points that ggplot is using on the x-axis?

I tried using `tibble(x = seq(0, 9, 0.005))` as my input data, but no change.

### Current output:

```
peaks <- list(p2 = list(name = "peak 1", tr = 2.5, sigma = 0.00873037869711973, 
    k = 0.25), p5 = list(name = "peak 2", tr = 5, sigma = 0.0174607573942395, 
    k = 1.5), p7 = list(name = "peak 3", tr = 7, sigma = 0.0244450603519352, 
    k = 2.5))

ggplot(tibble(x = 0), aes(x = x)) +
  stat_function(fun = function(x) rowSums(mapply(dnorm,
                                                 mean = sapply(peaks, function(x) x$tr), 
                                                 sd = sapply(peaks, function(x) x$sigma),
                                                 MoreArgs = list(x = x)))) + 
  xlim(0, 9) +
  ylim(0, 50) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

([thanks Roland](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54940903/8675075))

### Desired output:

[image]

This was done with a data frame, but I like the `stat_function()` approach, if possible. Thanks.

Comment: Use the `n` parameter of `stat_function`. See the documentation.